# how to get user profile details of gigya user from Hybris

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, gigya

I have Implemented RAAS(Registration as a service) with gigya for Hybris eCommerce platform. There are other source of registration as well so wanted to get details fro user profile via email id.

Below are code snippet.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.gigya.socialize.GSObject
import com.gigya.socialize.GSResponse
import de.hybris.platform.cms2.model.site.CMSSiteModel
import de.hybris.platform.gigya.gigyaservices.api.exception.GigyaApiException
import de.hybris.platform.gigya.gigyaservices.constants.GigyaservicesConstants
import de.hybris.platform.gigya.gigyaservices.utils.GigyaUtils
import de.hybris.platform.store.BaseStoreModel
import de.hybris.platform.util.Config

def gigyaLoginService = spring.getBean('gigyaLoginService')
def baseStoreService = spring.getBean('baseStoreService')
def gigyaService = spring.getBean('gigyaService')

BaseStoreModel baseStoreModel = baseStoreService.getBaseStoreForUid('electronics');
CMSSiteModel cmsSiteModel = baseStoreModel.getCmsSites().stream().findFirst().get()

final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

final Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
params.put("profile.email", "rj@gmail.com");
params.put("extraProfileFields", Config.getString("gigya.extra.fields","languages,address,phones,education,honors,publications,patents,certifications,professionalHeadline,bio,industry,specialties,work,skills,religion,politicalView,interestedIn,relationshipStatus,hometown,favorites,followersCount,followingCount,username,locale,verified,timezone,likes"));
params.put("include",Config.getString("gigya.basic.include", "loginIDs,emails,profile,data,preferences,groups"));

// Add environment details to getAccountInfo call
params.put("environment", GigyaUtils.getEnvironmentDetails());
final GSObject gigyaParams = convertMapToGsObject(mapper, params);
println("Gigya profile search parameters:: "+gigyaParams);
final GSResponse res = gigyaService.callRawGigyaApiWithConfigAndObject("accounts.search", gigyaParams,
        cmsSiteModel.getGigyaConfig(), GigyaservicesConstants.MAX_RETRIES, GigyaservicesConstants.TRY_NUM);
println(res)


def GSObject convertMapToGsObject(final ObjectMapper mapper, final Map<String, Object> parms)
{
    GSObject gigyaParams = new GSObject();
    try
    {
        gigyaParams = new GSObject(mapper.writeValueAsString(parms));
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        final String msg = "Error creating gigya request parmeters";
        println(e)
        throw new GigyaApiException(msg);
    }
    return gigyaParams;
}
```

But getting exception below.

```
Script execution has failed [reason: de.hybris.platform.gigya.gigyaservices.api.exception.GigyaApiException: Invalid parameter value]
```

I don't find any reference to get user profile details via email id.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a [`accounts.search` REST](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CUSTOMER_DATA_CLOUD/8b8d6fffe113457094a17701f63e3d6a/b32ce0918af44c3ebd7e96650fa6cc1d.html) call to get the profile details. This link also has a Java code sample and [its child link](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CUSTOMER_DATA_CLOUD/8b8d6fffe113457094a17701f63e3d6a/41392acf70b21014bbc5a10ce4041860.html) has many examples of the query. In your case, your `where` condition will be like this:

```
... where profile.email="test@example.com"
```

I hope you already use the application key and secret or a bearer token when sending requests. Remember that each REST API request must contain identification and authorization parameters.

Comment: trying same --> given code snippet working for login and there only difference is gigyaUid is getting  passed, here I am trying to send email id , and it''s not working.

tried sample example as well , now getting "Forbidden","errorMessage":"Sensitive Data Sent Over Http","errorCode":403006"

Comment: I am trying with groovy

Comment: Raushan Kumar
 You get that error when using a secret over non-SSL (https) connection.
also, for getAccountInfo, you need to pass the user's UID, not email address.

Comment: Hi @Levi
Yeah for login getting gigyaUid and that is getting pass and login works fine, there is other 3-4 system they are also capable of doing registration of user and data is getting send to gigya cdc but they are having info as email id so wanted to get user details from gigya based on email.
do you see any issue with above script , why parameter is invalid

Comment: You are getting invalid param error in the first example because profile.email is not a valid parameter name... I am not sure how Hybris works, but calling accounts.search for all users just to then do a getAccountInfo call seems like the wrong way around. search is a very heavy operation on our end and not recommended (might not even be supported) for something like that.  If all the users already 100% have an account in gigya, can't you just save their UID someplace in hybris, so you know who they are without needing to call accounts.search every time?